# Error when starting .Net-Application from ThinApp-Application

Tags: vmware-thinapp

one of our customers uses SAP through VMWare ThinApp.

In SAP there is a button that launches an .Net application from a server. When starting the .Net-application directly, there is no error. If the user tries to start the application by clicking the button in the ThinApp-Application, it displays the following errors:

```
Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Library

R6034
An application has made an attempt to load the C runtime library incorrectly.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.
```

After clicking "OK" it displays:

```
Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Library

Runtime Error!

R6030
- CRT not initialized
```

So, does the customer have to install some components into his ThinApp (if yes, which?) to get things working?

Regards,

inno

**----- [EDIT] -----**

@Sean:

It's installed the following way: The .exe of the .Net-Application is on a mapped drive on a server. All clients have the requirements installed (.Net-framework for example) and start the .exe from the mapped drive.

The ThinApp-Application tries to start this application and throws the mentioned exceptions. AFAIK there are no entry points for this application configured.

What I should also mention is: The .Net-Application crashes during execution. That means, we have a debug mode implemented that shows what the application is doing. The application shows what it's doing and after some steps it crashes.

The interesting point is: It's a .Net-application, not a C++ Application.

Comment: in that application is there any component that may leverage some legacy/unmanaged code? also check with the developer if there is any requirement to satisfy for third party components, if any.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how the application was packaged ultimately. When you say you launch the .net application directly, is that installed in the base operating system as another entry point for that ThinApp?